# How can I use indices in the subset function

Tags: r, subset

New to R programming and have a simple question about the subset function. I am hoping to use indices instead of names of columns in the subset function.

In the airquality dataset for example, instead of

```
   subset(airquality, Temp > 80, select = c(Ozone, Temp))
```

I want to use the column indices of the Temp and Ozone columns

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your comment.

Comment: Sorry about that. In your solution, subset(airquality, Temp > 80, select = c(1,4)), I would still have to mention 'Temp'

Comment: Doesn't it give the same output as your code?

Comment: @PrasannaJoshi, why do you want to use the index rather than the name? The name would be much more reliable.

Comment: It is always good to mention the column names as indexing can get wrong whenever we filter columns or change the positions.

Comment: The reason I am using indices is that, in the application, column names would be changing for different data frames. I want to pick the columns by specific index every time.

Comment: Try: `subset(airquality, get(names(airquality)[4]) > 80, c(1, 4))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use

```
subset(airquality, Temp > 80, select = c(1,4))
```

Based on the comments by the OP, using `get` to subset the rows (provided by @Ananda Mahto in the comments) is needed

```
subset(airquality, get(names(airquality)[4]) > 80, c(1, 4))
```